# How to read a big (593683 bytes) file in c?

Tags: c, file

I am trying to read a file which is maximum of size 4gb. But it always skips/detects eof before it actually appears. I am trying to read this [file](http://textfiles.com/etext/FICTION/2000010.txt) with the following code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<stdbool.h>
    #define buffer 8000

   int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    FILE *in = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
    if(!in){
        printf("File open failed %p\n",in);
        return 0;
    }
    char* tmp = malloc(buffer*sizeof(char));
    int filesize = 0;
    while(1){

        filesize = fread(tmp,1,buffer,in);
        if(filesize == buffer){
            printf("%d] %s\n\n",filesize,tmp);
        }else if(filesize < buffer){
            printf("%d] %s\n\n",filesize,tmp);
            break;
        }
    }
    free(tmp);
    fclose(in);
    return 0;
 }
```

Last buffer:

> 1683] e missing vessel tell  ...

After that it prints[note it does not print filesize] ]:

> me, perhaps speak to me. A gesture of his might destroy me, a single
>   word chain me on board.
>   But ten was about to strike.  The moment had come for me to leave my
>   room, and join my companions...
>   EOF detected 1683 !

Comment: You don't need the unreliable `feof`. `fread` will tell you when it's done. (But it will *not* zero-terminate your strings!)

Comment: What do you mean "stops"? Did it print your "EOF detected"?

Comment: @usr2564301 `feof` isn't unreliable. It is the only *reliable* way to see if the end-of-file was reached...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: well, `fread` will tell you when you cannot read any further anyway.

Comment: @paul the last line of output is same as i quoted(yellow block). and yes it prints eof detected

Comment: There's a big difference between 593683 and 4GB. If you really are trying to read a small file that's less than 600K, you can just declare an array outside of `main`, e.g. `static char buffer[1024 * 1024];`. And then just read the whole file with one `fread`.

Comment: What was `filesize` on the last read?

Comment: @user338 i meant the program should handle max 4gb. I have a program that works on 16000 bytes and crashes the terminal(Fedora 25) when i read the file mentioned in question. That is why i need the program to handle large (max 4gb) files

Comment: @user3386109: I beg to differ. If I have to process such a buffered input, it's better to start and test with a relatively small buffer. That way you can more easily catch corner cases. If this code works, it will also work with a much larger buffer.

Comment: The code looks correct. You must take a debugger to inspect the buffer in the last read. If all the text is there, then there is a problem with the terminal. You could try an `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: @paul the code does print file, but it also prints contents from previous buffer although it should stop printing as soon as eof detected. The starting lines of prev buffer is:    _8000]  madman; fortunately I resisted the desire,
and stretched myself on my bed to quiet my bodily agitation.
My nerves were somewhat calmer, but in my excited brain I saw_   whereas after last line it starts printing from: _me, perhaps speak to me.
A gesture of his might destroy me, a single word chain me on board._ which is somewhere in middle of the prev buffer

Comment: What are you wanting to do with the text after your read it? I ask because it is just text. You could easily use `fgets` or `getline` to read it as a text file rather than using `fread`. If you are just loading the file into a buffer, then either approach will work, but depending on what you want to do with the text, there are advantages/disadvantages to each.

Answer (score 2):

The code is working basically correctly — the last buffer is indeed 1683 bytes long, and does indeed start `e missing vessel`.  Observe the results of running:

```
$ tail -c 1683 2000010.txt
e missing vessel tell us by its nationality that of Captain Nemo?

I hope so.  And I also hope that his powerful vessel has conquered
the sea at its most terrible gulf, and that the Nautilus has survived
where so many other vessels have been lost!  If it be so--if Captain
Nemo still inhabits the ocean, his adopted country, may hatred be
appeased in that savage heart!  May the contemplation of so many wonders
extinguish for ever the spirit of vengeance!  May the judge disappear,
and the philosopher continue the peaceful exploration of the sea!
If his destiny be strange, it is also sublime.  Have I not understood
it myself?  Have I not lived ten months of this unnatural life?
And to the question asked by Ecclesiastes three thousand years ago,
"That which is far off and exceeding deep, who can find it out?"
two men alone of all now living have the right to give an answer----

CAPTAIN NEMO AND MYSELF.


The end of Project Gutenberg etext of "Twenty Thousand Leagues
Under the Sea"


I have made the following changes to the text:

PAGE LINE ORIGINAL CHANGED TO
  32    36  mizen-mast             mizzen-mast
  66     5  Arronax                Aronnax
  87    33  zoophites              zoophytes
  89    22  aparatus               apparatus
  96    28  dirunal                diurnal
  97     8  Arronax                Aronnax
 123    23  porphry                porphyry
 141     8  Arronax                Aronnax
 146    30  sideral                sidereal
 177    30  Arronax                Aronnax
 223     4  commmit                commit
 258    16  swiftiest              swiftest
 274     2  occured                occurred


 $
```

You could add a cumulative size counter to your code, and print that value as well as the current buffer size.  I modified the code to only print the first 30 characters of each block too.  And you could print block numbers — there are 74 blocks of 8000 characters for 592,000 plus one of 1,683 for 593,683 total.  You were printing the data without constraints, so there were also 8000-1683 = 6317 stray characters left over from the penultimate block after the end of the final block.  There's no null terminator added by `fread()` — you aren't reading strings but you are reading blocks of bytes.

Making the counting changes yielded:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define buffer 8000

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *in = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!in)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "File open failed %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 0;
    }
    char *tmp = malloc(buffer * sizeof(char));
    if (tmp == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed for %d bytes\n", buffer);
        return 1;
    }
    int filesize = 0;
    int cum_size = 0;
    int block_no = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        filesize = fread(tmp, 1, buffer, in);
        cum_size += filesize;
        block_no++;
        printf("%2d:%6d:%4d] %.30s\n", block_no, cum_size, filesize, tmp);
        if (filesize < buffer)
            break;
    }
    free(tmp);
    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output started:

```
 1:  8000:8000] **The Project Gutenberg Etext 
 2: 16000:8000] ndemnify and hold the Project,
 3: 24000:8000] he question seemed buried,
ne
 4: 32000:8000] rrival in New York several per
 5: 40000:8000] boy, who had accompanied
me i
 6: 48000:8000]  calls himself Canadian calls 
 7: 56000:8000] lp in chasing
a whale they ha
```

and ended:

```
"Exactly, Consei
68:544000:8000] e our arrival on board, and wh
69:552000:8000] e have entered upon it, let us
70:560000:8000] ric cable lying
on the bottom
71:568000:8000] ook part in the battle of Comt
72:576000:8000]  coldly.  "And I advise you no
73:584000:8000] e of guns and the netting.  Th
74:592000:8000]  madman; fortunately I resiste
75:593683:1683] e missing vessel tell us by it
```

By explicitly limiting the number of characters printed in each block, I mostly avoid issues of null-termination of strings.  However, strictly, you should be ensuring that you do not try to read beyond the end of the `tmp` buffer.  If I wanted to print the full buffer read, I should use:

```
printf("%2d:%6d:%4d] %.*s\n", block_no, cum_size, filesize, filesize, tmp);
```

You might use:

```
printf("%d] %.*s\n", filesize, filesize, tmp);
```